# Can oauth be used to generate direct links to a third party service?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I have a client that wants to integrate to my software with the intention to do the following:
- link their users to our platform and then access particular information (oauth first and then transmit data [REST])
- present links to the user to then directly access authenticated pages on our website (SSO?).

Is it possible to this via oauth? Or is an SSO (SAML) needed for the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question requires some more description, but get your leads from below notes.

SSO does single sign on for set of applications. Typically for internal applications within a security domain.

SAML-SSO does remote user authentication, federate users between different security domains and does single sign on for the applications. Typically for external applications on different security domains can be single sign on.

OAUTH does remote user authentication at authentication server and authorize user or others to give permission to access resource on the resources server. This does not federate the user nor single sign on of applications (as you need in your case).

Hope this helps to understand what exactly you need or you could modify the question to get expected answer.